# Ssh into ubuntu guest machine from mac os host as root user

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, root

So I have set up an ubuntu virtual machine in virtualbox and the user called dhruv and the hostname dhruvhadoop.

I have set up a port forwarding rule from the network settings with name ssh, no host IP, 3022 as host port , no guest ip and 22 as guest port.

Then I installed the openssh-server on my guest machine and restarted my guest machine.

Then from my host machine I was able to: `$ ssh -p 3022 dhruv@127.0.0.1`

However I was not able to: `$ ssh -p 3022 root@127.0.0.1` Error message comes up like: permission denied (publickey, password)

I thought I do not know the password to my root user for guest machine.

I went to my guest machine and did

`$$ su -`

And wrote password and it turned out to be wrong.

So I did,

`$$ sudo passwd root` And I set up the password.

Then I was able to do:

`$$ su -` And it works and brings me up to the root user.

However the ssh from my host to guest with root gives me the same problem.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The sshd probably disabled the root logon.  Check file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, find the line `PermitRootLogin no`, replace `no` with `yes` and save it.  Then restart the sshd by `service sshd restart`.